# Explicit animations using only an .animation modifier don't work

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I am playing with SwiftUI and I noticed that code from [this Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions) doesn't work as it supposed to. I want to have an animation applied for a `scaleEffect` but not for a `rotationEffect` but doing this as it is done in a mentioned tutorial doesn't work - when the `.animation(nil)` is added, there is no animation at all. Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

```
struct ContentView: View {
      @State private var showDetail = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showDetail.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(showDetail ? 90 : 0))
                .animation(nil)
                .scaleEffect(showDetail ? 1.5 : 1)
                .padding()
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the `.animation` before `.rotationEffect` and it will not be applied on the effect

```
Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .scaleEffect(showDetail ? 1.5 : 1)
                .padding()
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(showDetail ? 90 : 0))
```

Comment: Ye, this should works but it doesn't! Animation for a `scaleEffect` and a `rotationEffect` is being played. I am not sure if there is a bug or my Xcode is broken.

Comment: @czater I checked in Xcode 11.2 Beta 2 and it works fine, the scaling effect is animated, while the rotation isn't

Comment: Yes, this is working perfectly fine with Xcode 11.2 Beta 2!

Comment: Ok with `rotationEffect` it works but when you change it to `position` it is not working anymore...
`.position(showDetail ? CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) : CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))`
This is weird :/

Comment: I have the same problem, in my case I am using xcode 11.2.1 and the .animation modifier doesn't work on IOS 13.2. When running on IOS 13.1 my animations work fine.